# 1からその整数までの奇数の和を求めたい

Tags: python

偶数はわかるのですが奇数には表し方はあるのでしょうか？
近いコードは書けたのですがその先が分かりません。

```
a = input('整数を入力：')
b = int(a)

s = 0
i = 1
while i <= b:
    s += i
    i += 1

print(s)
```

Comment: `sum(range(1,b+1,2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`変数 % 2 == 0`が偶数なので、その反対が奇数なのは理解頂けると思います。
記述方法は
`変数 % 2 != 0` または `変数 %2 == 1`になります。

それを踏まえて一つ前の質問の答えを応用して

```py
a = input('整数を入力 ')
goal = int(a)

total = 0
i = 1

while i <= goal :
    if i % 2 != 0 :
        total += i
    i += 1

print("合計は", total)
```

出力結果(入力した整数は10)

```
整数を入力 10
合計は 25
```

となります。

Answer (score 1):

whileは必要ないです
上限をnとします
nが偶数のとき：(n/2)²
nが奇数のとき：(n/2+1)²
よって

```
a = input('整数を入力：')
b = int(a)

if b % 2 == 0:
    print( int( (b//2)**2 ) )
else:
    print( int( (b//2+1)**2 ) )
```